# SQL Query for "criss cross" lookup to get a "completed" table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

SQL newbie here looking at optimizing an SQL Query in Access 2007. The solution I've found does work but I'm not liking it at all because I believe it's not a very elegant way to do it. Here's the RESULT table I'm after:

```
Product  | Manufacturer        | Price
---------|---------------------|-----------------
Apples   | FreshFoods inc.     | n.a.
Oranges  | FreshFoods inc.     | $2.99
Lemons   | FreshFoods inc.     | $1.55
Lemonade | FreshFoods inc.     | n.a.
Apples   | NatureOnlineShop    | $5.00
Oranges  | NatureOnlineShop    | n.a.
Lemons   | NatureOnlineShop    | $4.50
Lemonade | NatureOnlineShop    | n.a.
Apples   | ExpensiveFoods inc. | $16.00
Oranges  | ExpensiveFoods inc. | $49.00
Lemons   | ExpensiveFoods inc. | n.a.
Lemonade | ExpensiveFoods inc. | n.a.
```

generated from:
1. Table PRODUCTS

```
ID | Name    
---|-------- 
1  | Apples  
2  | Oranges
3  | Lemons
4  | Lemonade
```

2. Table MANUFACTURER

```
ID | Name
---|--------------------
1  | FreshFoods inc.
2  | NatureOnlineShop
3  | ExpensiveFoods inc.
```

and 3. Table PRICES

```
ID | ID_Product | ID_Manufacturer | Price
---|------------|-----------------|----------
1  | 2          | 1               | $2.99
2  | 3          | 1               | $1.55
3  | 3          | 2               | $4.50
4  | 1          | 2               | $5.00
5  | 1          | 3               | $16.00
6  | 2          | 3               | $49.00
```

What I've got (hacked together) and what works is:

```
SELECT      
          PRODUCTS.Name as Product, MANUFACTURER.Name as Manufacturer, PRICES.Price as Price
FROM    
          PRODUCTS, MANUFACTURER, PRICES
WHERE 
          PRICES.ID_Product = PRODUCTS.ID AND
          PRICES.ID_Manufacturer = MANUFACTURER.ID 

UNION SELECT    

          PRODUCTS.Name as Product, MANUFACTURER.Name as Manufacturer, "n.a." as Price
FROM      
          PRODUCTS, MANUFACTURER
WHERE   
          (10000*PRODUCTS.ID + MANUFACTURER.ID) 
          NOT IN 
          (SELECT 10000*PRICES.ID_Product + PRICES.ID_Manufacturer FROM PRICES)
```

I especially am not fond of the 10000*.... part and would be thankful to an alternative solution of how to do these "completed criss cross" lookups.. no idea how these are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an [implicit `CROSS JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) between *PRODUCTS* and *MANUFACTURER*:

```sql
SELECT
    PRODUCTS.ID AS ID_Product,
    PRODUCTS.Name AS Name_Product,
    MANUFACTURER.ID AS ID_Manufacturer,
    MANUFACTURER.Name AS Name_Manufacturer
FROM PRODUCTS, MANUFACTURER;
```

Then you can use that as a subquery which you `LEFT JOIN` to *PRICES*.  I tested this query in Access 2010 and it returns the rows I believe you want, but you may need to adjust their order:

```sql
SELECT
    sub.Name_Product AS [Product],
    sub.Name_Manufacturer AS [Manufacturer],
    IIf(
            PRICES.Price Is Null,
            'n.a.',
            Format(PRICES.Price,'$0.00')
        ) AS [Price]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            PRODUCTS.ID AS ID_Product,
            PRODUCTS.Name AS Name_Product,
            MANUFACTURER.ID AS ID_Manufacturer,
            MANUFACTURER.Name AS Name_Manufacturer
        FROM PRODUCTS, MANUFACTURER
    ) AS sub
    LEFT JOIN PRICES
    ON
            (sub.ID_Manufacturer = PRICES.ID_Manufacturer)
        AND (sub.ID_Product = PRICES.ID_Product);
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want one row for each combination of product and manufacturer, regardless of whether there is a price listing for that combination.  Where there *is* a price listing, you want to include that in your result.

It's funny that you call it a "criss cross" lookup, because "CROSS JOIN" the SQL term for taking all combinations of rows, one from one table and one from another, which is just what you want for the first part.  You don't actually have to say the "CROSS" part.

As for cases where there is no price for a given (product, manufacturer), that's what outer joins are for.

More conventional SQL for this job might look like this:

```
SELECT
  PRODUCTS.Name AS Product,
  MANUFACTURER.Name AS Manufacturer,
  COALESCE(PRICES.Price, 'n.a.') AS Price
FROM
  PRODUCTS
  JOIN MANUFACTURER
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PRICES
    ON PRICES.ID_Product = PRODUCTS.ID
      AND PRICES.ID_Manufacturer = MANUFACTURER.ID
```

That assumes that your prices are actually strings, so that it makes sense to store them in the same result column as the string 'n.a.'.  If they are a numeric data type then you might be better off just accepting `NULL` in your results instead of the string 'n.a.'.